# My brother asked me to explain a algebra problem. How should I explain it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

So the problem is:

$$\frac{4}{x}+\frac{6}{2}=x$$
And we solved it using the pq formula. But than he asked me:

> How do I know when I should apply pq to similar equations like this
>   and not just:
>
> $$4 + 3 = x^2$$
>
> $$x = \sqrt{7}$$ ?
>
> Do I have to just test to find out if its wrong, and than just try all
>   possible solutions until I find the correct one or can I see it some
>   how?

I saw right away how to solve it but I do not really know why, so long ago I dealt with problems like this. Anyone have a idea how to explain it?

Comment: What's the pq formula?

Comment: I think this is a more suitable tag not abstract-algebra.

Comment: http://static2.devote.se/gallery/big/20100322/de7d23e351943685497e8647b4eaabaf.jpg

Comment: Changed the tag

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the question correctly? The equations are strange.

Comment: I think pq is something almost only we in Sweden use, at least the name pq.

Comment: noo, we use it in Germany as well! I was glad to see this is common in Sweden as well :)

Comment: yes I am shure.

Comment: pq method is the quadratic formula, I presume.

Comment: why is the tag "normal-subgroups" ?

Comment: you can solve ALL quadratic equations with the pq formula!

Comment: @ChickenP  The $pq$ formula states that the solution to the monic quadratic equation $x^2 + px + q = 0$ is $$x = \frac{-p \pm \sqrt{p^2 - 4q}}{2}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may help if you write your equation as you might on paper: $$\frac{4}{x}+\frac{6}{2}=x.$$ Then, supposing $x\neq 0$, you can see that to remove the $x$ in the denominator of the first fraction you should multiply all top terms by $x$ to get $$\frac{4\times x}{x}+\frac{6\times x}{2}=x\times x.$$ Now we can simplify to get $$4+3x=x^2.$$ Basically you will need to learn the rules of algebra and that can often be helped by writing things out "nicely". Rearranging you then get $x^2-3x-4=0$ which you can solve using the "pq" formula.

Comment: Yes he gets it now. First post so did not know how to make the expression look that way, reading the faq now. He says thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome ! Welcome to SE.

Answer (score 3):

He multiplied it out wrong $$4 + 3x = x^2$$ which is a quadratic which can be solved using the pq formula.

Comment: How do you know he multiplied it out wrong?

Comment: By doing it correctly?